# Kotlin MPP conflates JVM code into my common codebase... how to force pure "common"

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlintest

My MPP library has android and jvm build: `kotlin { android(); jvm { /*...*/ } }`.

I've written a function that takes `kotlinx.datetime.DayOfWeek` and `kotlinx.datetime.Month` as parameters, but then inside of `commonTest`, the parameter types are translated into JVM, resulting in a type mismatch:

[image]

The function I'm calling is pretty ordinary:

[image]

So you can see that within `commonMain`, the provided type is not yet seen as a jvm type.

Is this an issue with kotlinx.datetime?  Is it not appropriate to include types from kotlinx.datetime in the api exposed by my common codebase?  Is there a way to dissuade the gradle plugin and compiler from making any optimizations to `commonMain`, which change its type signatures?

Comment: When running tests you need an actual implementation of the datetime (well, of everything), otherwise there'd be no code to run. You can't run `expect` code as it's just a definition.

Comment: Thanks for feedback but I'm pretty sure this isn't an issue with expect/actual.  The compiler knows how to run `commonTest` tests inside the runtime for each target, and there are also specific compiler errors for when there is no _actual_ of a given type for one or more configured targets.